# Creating list of dictionaries efficiently

Tags: python

I have implemented an approach to create a list of dictionaries, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of doing so (while preserving the order elements in both lists):

```
#global variable
dict_agriculture = []

col_name_agriculture = [tuple[0] for tuple in querycurs.description]
rows_agriculture = querycurs.fetchall()
for row in rows_agriculture:
    dict1 = dict(zip(col_name_agriculture, list(row)))
    dict_agriculture.append(dict1)
```

Comment: I can't see any reason for `list(row)`, change that to `row` instead

Comment: Which DB backend are you using here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension here; its more efficient at creating the final list. Don't use `.fetchall()` when iteration will do, don't use `tuple` as a variable name, and there is no need to call `list` on each row:

```
fields = [tup[0] for tup in querycurs.description]
dict_agriculture = [dict(zip(fields, row)) for row in querycurs]
```

Comment: Sorry, but how will the program understand that querycurs contains all the row elements if I don't tell it explicitly to do so, for example: `querycurs.execute('SELECT * FROM Agriculture')` and `rows_agriculture = querycurs.fetchall()`

Comment: @JamesHallen: the cursor object itself acts like an iterator; looping over it with a `for` loop yields rows. `.fetchall()` is just a method to return a full list, but you are not going to keep that list when building a *new* list, anyway.

Comment: @JamesHallen: And how does `.fetchall()` know what rows to fetch? You called `.execute()` on the cursor, so from that point on the cursor points to the results for that query, and either using the cursor as an iterator or by calling `.fetchone()` or `.fetchall()` you retrieve the matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using sqlite.

In that case, the most efficient way would be to set [`row_factory`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) to the built-in [`Row`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) type, which is implemented in C, and will be faster than any equivalent code in Python.

For example...

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(...)
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
# Now queries will return objects which act as both a tuple, and a dictionary,
# so you can just do...
querycurs = con.cursor()
querycurs.execute(...)
dict_agriculture = querycurs.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read this right, you have a query cursor, where the .description property is a list of tuples with field names as the first item.
You then want to read the rows, turning each row list into a row dict using the row names from the tuple.

This can be done with a list comprehension:

```
col_name_agriculture = [tuple[0] for tuple in querycurs.description]
dict_agriculture = [dict(zip(col_name_agriculture, row) for row in querycurs]
```

Consider also how the final list will be used - a generator expression may be usable there if it is to be used in order.